# Rotating proxies with Python Requests?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, proxies

I'm building few functions to automate some part of my Google's searching and my IP get blocked after about 10-20 requests.

So I tried to build a function which scrapes a list of proxies and send it through the Requests library, but I'm not able to send only working proxies.

I tried try and except method, as you can see in my code and it didn't work

Also, I thought of using if/else, but I don't know with which logic to use for this method

I googled it and saw some solutions with scrapy/selenium but I prefer to avoid them at this point and stick to what I know rather than starting learning new stuff due to lack of time.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
import re

def get_proxy():

    ports = []
    proxxies = []
    final_server= []
    url = 'https://sslproxies.org'

    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')



    ports = re.findall(r'<td>(\d+)<', str(soup))

    proxxies = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(soup))

    for proxxi, port  in zip(proxxies,ports):
        final_server.append(proxxi+':'+port)


    print(final_server)


    ran_pro = {'https':random.choice(final_server)}
    print(ran_pro)
    return ran_pro

def proxy_test(test_url):
 while 1:
  try:
      proxy = get_proxy
      print(proxy)
      r=requests.get(test_url,proxies=proxy,timeout=5)
      print(r.status_code)
      return proxy
      break
      except:
      print('didnt work')
      pass
```

I know that I can encounter 2 different problems:

1. The Proxy was blacklisted and I will get a ProxyError
2. The Proxy simply doesn't work and I will get a TimeoutError

My problem is that I can't understand why the below code does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you use regex then you don't need `BeautifulSoup` and you can use `response.text` instead of `str(soup)`

Comment: what means "does not work" ? Do you get error ? Always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you forgot `()` in `proxy = get_proxy()`

Comment: you don't need `break` after `return`. It will be never executed.

Comment: the one of the biggest mistake - you don't display exception so you can't see what is the problem - You may have different problem then you expected and you will not know it - `except Exception as ex: print("ex:", ex)`. And frankly, you have problem different then blacklisted and timeout.

Comment: Thanks, @furas, what other problem do I have? Can I put two error messages at one exception?

Comment: you have proble bacause you forgot `()` in `get_proxy()`. You should see it if you run code without `try/except` or at least print exception.

Comment: you can use many `except` with different exceptions -  `except ProxyError as ex: print("Proxy Error:", ex)` `except TimeoutError as ex: print("Timeout Error:", ex)` . Or `except (ProxyError, TimeoutError) as ex: print("Error:", ex)`